# Connection error with cloudant db dedicated service on CIO Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have created an app on CIO bluemix platform under my org. Then I added cloudant DB dedicated service and did a bind of the service with the app. The hello world Node JS starter works for the app. However, when I try to connect to the cloudant db by extending the starter app downloaded as the starter kit and cloud foundry cli, then it give 'connect ECONNREFUSED ' error. I have used the proper credentials. I also tried to launch the db using the web console that comes by clicking on the cloudant service icon, but it times out. Can you suggest what could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the hostname in your cloduant credentials file and add to your PC's host file:

windows sample:
9.45.69.22  23199ddc-775f-4ca5-91aa-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-bluemix.cloudant.com # DEV MOOC

Comment: I tried to start the app once without adding the host entry and it gave connect ETIMEDOUT this time. Also, I used the ip that was provided in the error message to add to the hosts file. Still the same error came. Is this correct thing to so? I would also like to add that I tried to connect to an existing cloudant DB instance on another bluemix platform through the same code by just changing the credentials and without adding anything to hosts file and that got connected.

Comment: You can also try posting your questions to support@cloudant.com.